# Orthographic projection in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I need assistance in understanding orthographic projection in asymptote.

```
currentprojection=orthographic(x,y,z);
```

Specifying `x`, `y` and `z`, one can rotate the figure in 3D but how do I decide on these numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changes in `x`, `y` and `z` will not rotate the `3d` object,
rather the camera position will be changed. 
A simple procedure can help to set up the projection parameters:

First, set the `2d` size of the picture, e.g.

```
size(200);
```

Next, import some of the modules, that support `3d`:

```
import three;
```

Start with some values for the camera position, imagine that this is a corner of the box, from which you are looking at the origin.

```
currentprojection=orthographic(2,2,2);
```

Place a simple object to start, e.g. a unit coordinate lines at the origin:

```
draw(O--(1,0,0),red);
draw(O--(0,1,0),green);
draw(O--(0,0,1),blue);
```

Now, you can run this `sample.asy` file:

```
size(200);
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(2,2,2);   
triple O=(0,0,0);    
dot(O);
label("$O$",(0,0,0),N);    
draw(O--(1,0,0),red);
draw(O--(0,1,0),green);
draw(O--(0,0,1),blue);
```

with `asy -V sample.asy > ocamera.asy`. An interactive viewer will let you 
change the view point as you like, and then `right-double-click` will bring a menu. Click `Camera` and current camera settings will be saved in `ocamera.asy` file, looking something like:

```
currentprojection=orthographic(
camera=(0.961388410434579,3.28630597183905,-0.564352559252),
up=(0.000558361334852193,0.00103708683243738,0.00699025170673149),
target=(7.76288755499621e-17,7.76288755499621e-17,7.76288755499621e-17),
zoom=0.505067952995518);
```

which can be copied into sample.asy and edited, for example, like this:

```
currentprojection=orthographic(
camera=(1,3.3,-0.5),
up=(0,0,1),
target=(0,0,0),
zoom=0.5);
```

This will give you a starting point.

Comment: Excellent .. 
But this method is not working inside a latex document. For example

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}[width=10cm,height=10cm]

THE ASY CODE

\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


1. It is working when the sample.asy consists of only THE ASY CODE. How to solve this issue ? 

2. It would be nice to have that interactive viewer accessible from within Texmaker.

Comment: Am I correct that `currentprojection=orthographic(2,2,2);` and `currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,3);` are the same in all cases? I.e., the vector only specifies the direction?

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Yes! by the definition of orthographic projection!